# how do i make java add instead of cancentate?

Tags: java

```
public class investment {   
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int i=0;

        Scanner Pay = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("how many years do u want to put in the money for? ");
        int years = Pay.nextInt();

        Scanner Py = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("how much do u want to invest? ");
        double money = Py.nextDouble();


        while (i<=years){
            i++;            
            double pr=.10;       
            double finall=(money*pr)+money;           
            System.out.print(finall);
        }    
    }
}
```

Why does this outprint an ip address instead of a legit number?

Comment: An IP address?.

Comment: What is it printing, exactly?

Comment: `+=` or `++` or `+` to add?

Comment: Can you show us what the output looks like?

Comment: why do you open a new Scanner ? Just reuse the old one.

Comment: Try to replace System.out.print with System.out.println to get rid of that "IP address"

Comment: Also, watch out with your variable naming. Typically, the convention in Java is to name variables with lower case first letters. So your `Pay` and `Py` variables should properly be named `pay` and `py`. Otherwise, it makes it hard to distinguish between variables and class names.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out

Answer (score 4):

I think this looks like an IP-Adress because you print in the loop, and you are printing comma values(double values).

Try printing it at the end of the while loop or use `System.out.println()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (i<=years){
        i++;

    double pr=.10;

        double finall=(money*pr)+money;


        System.out.print(finall);
```

You are printing in a loop, and you print each `double` unadorned - no spaces or newlines to separate them. Use `System.out.println` to have each on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to save the total back to the same variable:

```
money=(money*pr)+money;
System.out.print(money);
```

Btw you can also express it as:

```
money += money*pr;
```

or also

```
money *= 1 + pr;
```